# Read numeric value from txt. file and compare it to condition Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm new to Python and working on final project for my degree. I want to write a Python         script which will read numeric value (like: 21, 23, 28 etc.) and compare it to value in the script. If the value matches it should execute another python script. Everything seem to work correctly, but the red value from file make no change in conditions matching. The script every time executes statement ELSE instead of IF while the condition is really true.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import sys
import os


check_period = 2
fo = open("/home/pi/thermometer1.txt", "r+")
str = fo.readline();
fo.close()


while True:
    fo = open("/home/pi/thermometer1.txt", "r+")
    str = fo.readline();
    if str < 25 :
        os.system("python /home/pi/servo/servo1/servo6.py")
        print str
        fo.close()
    else:
        os.system("python /home/pi/servo/servo1/servo1.py")
        print str
        fo.close()
    time.sleep(check_period)
```

One more question would be how to edit this script which will compare one .txt file with numeric value like. 23 to other .txt file with numeric value like. 27 and if condition is met execute another python script (similar like the code above). Thanks in advance for all comments.

Comment: You seem to have an infinite loop there.  Is that intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read from a text file, you get strings.  A string compared to an int will always evaluate to `False`.   Instead of

```
str = fo.readline()
```

which stores a string type in `str`, do

```
str = int(fo.readline())
```

but be warned that if the line contains a value that cannot be an `int`, you will get an error.

As an aside, you do not need to put semicolons after any of the lines in your code, and the variable name `str` should be avoided, because it is a Python built-in type.

Answer (score 2):

Reading from the file you get strings, not integers.  Since they're different (non-comparible) types, any comparison you do result in a consistent, but arbitrary value based on the types<sup>1</sup>.  Apparently, strings are considered greater than integers (for Cpython -- Other implementations might behave differently).

You need to construct an integer out of your string instead:

```
int_from_str = int(fo.readline())
```

---

While we're at it, there are much better ways to iterate over a file:

```
with open("/home/pi/thermometer1.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        int_from_str = int(fin)
        ...
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>On python3.x, any comparison other than `==` will raise an exception.</sup>

Comment: "Since they're different (non-comparible) types, any comparison you do will always return `False`." Actually, it will return `True` or `False` based on the alphabetic sorting order of the name of the type: `int` is always less than `str` for example, because `"int" < "str"`. As you say, this silliness is gone in Python 3.

Comment: @kindall -- Right.  I knew I was forgetting something.  I've updated to correct it.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @kindall That's true only for C classes that do not implement `tp_compare`. If you create a new class in python than that's not true anymore: `class c(object): def __lt__(self, other): return NotImplemented 5 < c() -> True` even though `"int" > "c"`. In this case I believe that CPython uses the objects `id` to do the comparison.

Comment: @Bakuriu -- You're probably correct for Cpython.  Ultimately that point here is that the ordering is consistent (with the same interpretter, you'll get the same result), but it's arbitrary (with different interpretters, you might get different results).  Digging any deeper into it than that isn't really worthwhile unless you can prove to me that you have a *really good reason* (at which point I'd probably try to convince that your really good reason isn't very good after all)  ;-).